# Problem with device, can ping, but not tftp to get from server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, tftp, tftpd

On a Ubuntu GNS3 VM, I am trying to setup an active online-device.

Here is the sketch of the Ifconfig on this GNS3 VM host:

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:7f:07:8c:49  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        ...
ens160: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.31.1.116  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 10.31.15.255
        ...
gns3tap0-1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::60a2:8ff:fe4d:5672  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 62:a2:08:4d:56:72  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        ...
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        ...
virbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ...
```

And also on this VM, I have a tftp service started, that will provides the device license files for the incoming requests. I have double-checked and this tftp service is up and working OK.

And here is the diagram of my GNS3 Project that has been setup on this GNS3 VM.
[image]
As you may find out, there is connection sequence as: **cloud <-> Cisco Router <-> Switch -> X-1, which is my device at the end**.

From my device console, I was able to ping outside network and VM, but somehow, I could not tftp the license file from it.

here is my device console log:

```
 #
 # execute ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=115 time=16.352 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=1 ttl=115 time=12.175 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=2 ttl=115 time=18.031 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=3 ttl=115 time=14.223 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 12.175/15.195/18.031 ms
 # execute ping 10.31.1.116
PING 10.31.1.116 (10.31.1.116): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.31.1.116: seq=0 ttl=63 time=11.037 ms
64 bytes from 10.31.1.116: seq=1 ttl=63 time=17.924 ms
64 bytes from 10.31.1.116: seq=2 ttl=63 time=14.249 ms

--- 10.31.1.116 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 11.037/14.403/17.924 ms
 # execute bios get 10.31.1.116 FX200FTQ2109C0PU.rom
tftp: timeout
Get BIOS file failed...
```

Any idea what could be wrong ? This is the first time I am trying to setup the devices in such environment. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks, Just corrected !

Comment: Since i see '8.8.8.8': Please do only use Google DNS servers if you want google to track all the domains you are browsing.